# Issue with Swift code syntax

Tags: swift, cocoa

I am attempting to get the height of an NSAttributedString with a fixed width. I am getting an error that says:

Use of unresolved identifier 'NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin'

Any help would be appreciated. My code is as follows:

```
let string: NSAttributedString = self.attributedStringValue
let width: CGFloat = self.frame.size.width * 0.95;
var rect: CGRect = string.boundingRectWithSize(CGSizeMake(width, CGFLOAT_MAX), options: NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin | NSStringDrawingUsesFontLeading, context: nil)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Swift 2 has changed many enum into option set types, replace your last line with this:

```
var rect: CGRect = string.boundingRectWithSize(CGSizeMake(width, CGFLOAT_MAX), options: [.UsesLineFragmentOrigin, .UsesFontLeading], context: nil)
```

If you want to know where the value names come, here's the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSString_AppKitAdditions/index.html#//apple_ref/c/tdef/NSStringDrawingOptions).